# c++ - Pointers and addresses

Tags: c++

I'm just playing around a little bit with reflection and I'm seeing something that doesn't make sense to me. The application pretty much asks you to type in the name of a class and if it founds it in the map, it creates a instance of that class and prints out the address of the object.

The first time i type in Derived1, It generates 1 address for example (0x00001), the second time i type in the same name it shows another address (0x00002) and the third time it keeps using the same address again.

How come i only get a new address for the second object and not for the rest of the objects?

This is by no means a problem, I'm just curious.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base
{
protected:
    int id;
public:
    Base(int _id)
        :id(_id)
    {
        std::cout << "Im the base class, and this is my address: " << this << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void PrintMyAddress() const = 0;
    void PrintId()
    {
        std::cout << "This is my ID: " << this->id << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1(int _id) : Base(_id){}
    void PrintMyAddress() const override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm derived 1, this is my address: " << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~Derived1(){}
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2(int _id) : Base(_id){}
    virtual void PrintMyAddress() const override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm derived 2, this is my address: " << this << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Derived2(){}
};

class Derived3 : public Derived2
{
public:
    Derived3(int _id) : Derived2(_id){}
    void PrintMyAddress() const override
    {
        std::cout << "I'm derived 3, this is my address: " << this << std::endl;
    }

    ~Derived3(){}
};

class Generate
{
private:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Base> (Generate::*SomeFunction)(int);
    std::map<std::string, SomeFunction> listFunction;

public:
    Generate()
    {
        this->MapClasses();
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::unique_ptr<Base> CreateDerived(int _id)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Base> tmp(new T(_id));
        return std::move(tmp);
    }

    void MapClasses()
    {
        this->listFunction["Derived1"] = &Generate::CreateDerived<Derived1>;
        this->listFunction["Derived2"] = &Generate::CreateDerived<Derived2>;
        this->listFunction["Derived3"] = &Generate::CreateDerived<Derived3>;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Base> Class(std::string _name)
    {
        if (this->listFunction.find(_name) != this->listFunction.end())
        {
            return std::move((this->*this->listFunction[_name])(rand() % 100));
        }
        else
        {
            std::unique_ptr<Base> itsnull;
            return std::move(itsnull);
        }
    }

    std::map<std::string, SomeFunction>& GetFunctionList()
    {
        return this->listFunction;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Generate gen;
    bool run = true;
    while (run)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "What class do you want to generate? Type in the name of the class: " << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::string className;
        std::cin >> className;
        if (className == "exit")
        {
            run = false;
            continue;
        }

        auto genclass = gen.Class(className);
        if (genclass.get())
        {
            genclass->PrintMyAddress();
            genclass->PrintId();
            std::cout << "This is my TypeID: " << typeid(*genclass).name() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Class couldn't be created because it doesn't exist..." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

This is a similar example but always shows the same address:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int* test = new int;
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    delete test;
}
```

Is the compiler optimizing everything after the second creation?

Comment: Why don't you change your `main()` so that it doesn't depend on some input that we can't see?

Comment: What input? Thats the entire code.

Comment: This input: `std::cin >> className;`.

Comment: Code is way too long. Is `PrintID` even relevant?

Comment: "Why this the pointer address which once"??? Interesting title man!

Comment: No mate, its just there to show you that it generates a new instance.

Comment: The code is actually not that long to be honest, you can copy and paste and run it and see for your self. Its just 1 base class, 3 derived classes and 1 generate class which creates objects. Nothing special at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code basically created a new object then deletes it each loop.

The address of the object is dependent on where the heap puts it. The heap is free to reuse space that's been recently free'd up (and it would be silly if it didn't) and so you are very likely to get repeat address's.

Comment: I've updated my code, I guess its the compiler which optimizes the code after the second time it creates the object then?

Comment: Its unlikely to be the compiler doing anything here - its the runtime heap which decides where objects get placed. And that can dynamically make deecisiong based on internal criteria and more importantly by other users of the heap between iterations (the std::cout and console subsystem are likely to use the heap aswell)

Comment: So i guess it could differ depending on the OS you are running the program on, because Quicky just said that he gets the same address running the program on linux gcc 4.9.0. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

When I test you code on Linux with gcc 4.9.0 and ask for Derived1 3 times I always obtain the same address (0xdead by example)
The reason is that compiler replace line

```
auto genclass = gen.Class(className);
```

by

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> genclass = gen.Class(className);
```

When the execution reach the end of the wile loop local variable genclass is destroyed
the unique_ptr do its job by deleting the object it points which  make the address 0xdead available for use
Next iteration will create a new object and reuse 0xdead addresse because it is available
In your case the memory allocation mechanism behind is perhaps slightly different and address is seen available only at third iteration

You can check the destruction of your object performed by unique_ptr by putting a breakpoint on Base destructor or adding an instruction like the following in the destructor :

```
std::cout << "Delete base whose address is " << this << std::endl;
```